# How can I write a regex to extract only digits with a certain string preceding them?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string (which contains JSON):

```
[{"type":[236]} , {"type":[2]} , {"type":[95]}, {"other":[33]}, {"other":[44]}]
```

I want to use a regex to extract only the TYPE numbers, so that the output is the following string:

```
[236 , 2 , 95]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: As usual: what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Why do you specifically want a regexp ? If the input is JSON, I'd use a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/java/) to handle this. It'll be built specifically to parse the above and handle edge cases etc.

Answer (score 5):

Why not parse it with a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/java/), then pull out all of the values from the resulting structure that point to `type` keys? Using a regular expression to parse text that's in a defined format like JSON is a good way to [go crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially do it with a regex, but a much better way would be to use a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/java/):

- It's arguably clearer in your code that you're dealing with JSON if you're using a dedicated JSON parser (regexes on their own can be rather cryptic)
- It'll be a heck of a lot easier to use
- It will be much more reliable, especially in corner cases where a regex might fall down (a properly implemented JSON parser should handle all cases correctly.)

So yes, you could probably hack together a regex to do it, but given the fact that there's a comprehensive JSON parser (the one I've linked to) freely available there's little sense in doing it the regex way.